# Odd java.lang.verifyerror on 4.0.3-4.0.4 devices

Tags: android, runtime-error, verifyerror

I hae been investigating the error for some days without any luck. I am not using exoplayer in my own code but I'm using Facebook audience ads. Don't know if it could be using it. Anyway, the app seems to crash while initialization. Could anybody guess why this is hapenning?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/exoplayer/MediaCodecUtil$ˎ
at com.my.package.name.onCreate(:4161)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Cheers.

Comment: From the exoplayer website: ExoPlayer’s standard audio and video components rely on Android’s MediaCodec API, which was released in Android 4.1 (API level 16). Hence they do not work on earlier versions of Android.

Comment: Understood thanks. Is there anyway to know wich library is using it?

Comment: yep, if you list the dependencies you will be able to find it. Try with gradle app:dependencies

Comment: Awesome, really useful tip. Didn't know I could do that. Thanks again. Facebook audience is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dmarin suggested. Exoplayer just works with api level >= 16. I was using Facebook audience network for monetization and they say in his docs that to be used I should be using api level 15. So, they are wrong here.

As seen in the dependency tree dumped by graldew in my app:

```
com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.15.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 24.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 -> 24.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0 -> 24.2.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0 -> 24.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.8
```

FAN is using it for its purposes, so, if you use this monetization solution at this time you will want to raise your API level to 16 if you don't want people using 4.03-4.04 to crash.

Cheers